# Invoke a lambda function from another lambda asynchronously for a string of input with different parameters using Java

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need to call my lambda - A from lambda - B. I have done the required code but need few clarifications.

```java
AWSLambda lambdaClient = AWSLambdaClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(region)
.withCredentials(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain()).build();

InvokeRequest request = new InvokeRequest().withClientContext(clientContext).withFunctionName(functionName)
          .withQualifier(alias).withPayload(payload).withInvocationType(InvocationType.Event);

InvokeResult response = lambdaClient.invoke(request);
```

I have a N number of table names which I need to pass from lambda B to lambda A one by one so that it can do the needful work on that DDB table.

The problem is `withPayload` takes a JSON payload which is passed to the lambda function.

I will pass the payload to lambda-B but then the code is calling `lambdaClient.invoke(request)` which will have all the table names and it will call our lambda-A. But handler function in the lambda-A expects a single table name.

I am not sure how to do this.

Also do i need to run this in a loop so that every time it takes new payload value and then calls `lambdaClient.invoke(request)` or does it happen automatically?

Answer (score -1):

You should create pyload with a single table name. In this case, you will have many payloads so you can have array of them and process them in a loop.

For Example:

```
InvokeRequest request = null;
InvokeResult response = null;
for(String payload : payloads){
  request = new InvokeRequest().withClientContext(clientContext).withFunctionName(functionName)
          .withQualifier(alias).withPayload(payload).withInvocationType(InvocationType.Event);
  response = lambdaClient.invoke(request);
}
```

In which case you will get that payload? Lamda normally runs on some event and a lambda cannot run more than 15 minutes(For more than 15 minutes you have to contact the AWS Support Team).

Comment: lambda timeout has increased to 15 minutes.

Comment: @testMyUnderstanding updated the time but have you got your answer?

Comment: I think so.. I will have to try out. The problem is I am getting the payload from CF template. I need to check now how to pass array using template.

Comment: @testMyUnderstanding you can fetch the data from that payload and make your own payload. use JSON library for the same.

Comment: I am thinking to maintain a properties file which will have my tablenames in an array.. then I can pass that array to my CF template's environment variable and this way i can get it in my lambda function

Comment: @testMyUnderstanding Do these table names are static? Another point is how are you triggering your Lambda B?